# Работа в ui потоке

Tags: android, java

Предположим выполняется какая-нибудь работа с ui, предположим, в цикле на карту устанавливаются маркеры и есть задача выполнить какую-нибудь анимацию с другим элементом. Предположим плавненько передвинуть кнопки по вертикале с координаты на координату. Может получится такой момент, что эти действия совпадут. Соответственно никакого плавного действия анимации не будет. Кнопка окажется сразу на нужной координате. Нужно этого избежать. Может кто-то знает какие-нибудь хитрости работы с такими ситуациями или есть какие-нибудь идеи?

Comment: в одном потоке действия выполняются последовательно, а не параллельно. И если вы запросите выполнение второго действия (анимации) в том потоке, где еще выполняется первое действие (заполнение карты), то второе действие встанет в очередь, и выполнится после завершения первого.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас используется именно анимация, то существует listener специально для таких ситуаций.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html вот более подробная информация.